# Hibernate Overwiriting Column values with NULL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

On Inserting/Saving the last element, hibernate is overwriting the earlier element's ManyToOne Column with NULL.  Below is detailed description.

I am creating few "State" objects and persisting them in to DB -

```
        Country usa = new Country ("USA", "330000000");
        State mi = new State("MI", "11000000", usa);
        State ca = new State("CA", "39900000", usa);
        State fl = new State("FL", "21300000", usa);

        countryRepository.save(usa); 
        stateRepository.save(mi); 
        stateRepository.save(ca); 
        stateRepository.save(fl);
```

**Hibernate is persisting the "State" objects into DB as expected, until it  reaches persisting the last  "State" object. This is where it is triggering the below query and inserting null value to country field**.

```
2019-09-09 11:45:37.390 DEBUG 9600 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    update
        state 
    set
        country_name=null 
    where
        country_name=?
2019-09-09 11:45:37.390 TRACE 9600 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [USA]
```

**So on the DB side, it has caused the `country` field of all previously persisted States(rows in table) to be set to null.**
Then it is persisting the last state -

```
2019-09-09 11:45:39.649 DEBUG 9600 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        state
        (country_name, population, name) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
2019-09-09 11:45:39.650 TRACE 9600 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [USA]
2019-09-09 11:45:39.650 TRACE 9600 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [21300000]
2019-09-09 11:45:39.650 TRACE 9600 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [FL]
```

The resulting DB table is as below - you can see null value for country_name of CA and MI, but not for FL which is the last Saved State.

```
mysql> select * from state;
+------+------------+--------------+
| name | population | country_name |
+------+------------+--------------+
| CA   | 39900000   | NULL         |
| FL   | 21300000   | USA          |
| MI   | 11000000   | NULL         |
+------+------------+--------------+
```

The java entity objects are as below:
State entity -

```
@Table(name="state")
@Entity
public class State {

    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;
    @Column(name="population") 
    String population;  

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="state_name")
    List<City> cities;

    @ManyToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
    Country country;  
    //getters and setters
```

and the Country entity -

```
@Table(name="country")
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;

    @Column(name="population")
    String population;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="country_name")
    List<State> states; 
    //getters and setters
```

Any hint's of why this behavior of overwriting country field with null value for every state except for the last. I am not expecting the null value for country for other states.

Comment: Is the behaviour the same if you first save the country, then assign the return value of `save()` to the individual states? Because now you're assigning the unmanaged country entity, and there are cascading rules.

Comment: changed to - `Country usa = new Country ("USA", "330000000");
     Country usa_persisted = countryRepository.save(usa); 

     State ca = new State("CA", "39900000", usa_persisted);
     State fl = new State("FL", "21300000", usa_persisted);
     State mi = new State("MI", "11000000", usa_persisted); `
          still the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `CascadeType.ALL` you don't need to do all this

```
countryRepository.save(usa); 
stateRepository.save(mi); 
stateRepository.save(ca); 
stateRepository.save(fl);
```

I'd recommend to make sure you add the states to the list of states in your country in your states' constructor and then just persisting the country. Also I would not use `FetchType.EAGER` and rather fetch when you do actually need it since it can cause a large amount of SQL statements

Comment: If that doesn't work, please share your repositories code and the code of your constructors

Comment: removing the cascade worked. But it's difficult to understand why it would modify entities (states) that have been already persisted.

Comment: if you did still like to take a look at the code (which is part of a graphql implementation), i can go ahead and share it over github or as a zip.

Comment: If you did not add the state to the list of states in your country from within the states' constructor then it makes sense, that the countries get overwritten.

Comment: 1. Country gets saved without a state 2. state 1 gets saved with country, country gets state added 3. state 2 gets saved with country, but country does not have any states in its field -> country entity gets overwritten and state 2 gets saved into countries states 4. same as 3. with state 3

Comment: @let me process this stuff.. but gr8 explanation... :-)

Comment: pushed the code to github: https://github.com/samshers/graphql-hibernate

Comment: I would expect the `update
        state 
    set
        country_name=null 
    where
        country_name=?` to be executed every time a state is saved, but it's getting executed only prior to saving the last state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199168/discussion-between-paul-daechert-and-samshers).